# C# 10 second timer on combox selected Index

Tags: c#, events, timer

After being out of scripting for ages I have decided to learn a programming language and I have gone for C#. I'm getting along pretty well but now for the first time I seem to have been faced with a problem that I have not been able to solve with google.

I am making a simulated aircraft system as a learning exercise and I want to invoke a loop when an option is selected from a drop down combobox.

I have a combobox/list with three options which simulates the starter switch, the values are (0)Off, (1)On, (2)Ignition Only . In the real aeroplane, when 'On' is selected the switch locks in place for 10 seconds and then releases. So what I am trying to achieve is :

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
      //Starter is off
      eng2Start.Value = 0;
   }

   if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
      //starter is on 
      //Start Timer
      eng2Start.Value = 1;

      if (eng2Tourqe >= 6000)
      {
         //open fuel valve
         // set Hot Start counter to 0
      }
      else 
      {
         //ensure fuel valve stays closed
         // set Hot Start counter to x+1
      }

      // End of Timer

      // set selected index back to 0
      (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 0)

   }
}
```

I have googled and googled and the more I read the more I am getting lost in this.   I have found answers containing a mass of code which I am not able to fully decipher just yet.

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Thanks  in advance for your time.

Comment: you want to wait for 10 seconds when On is selected from ComboBox right?

Answer (score 1):

You can Add `Timer` to your `Form` and Set the `Interval` property to `10000`(10 seconds).

from code:

```
if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
 //starter is on 
 //Start Timer
 timer1.Enabled=true;    
 }

 //in timer tick Event write the following:
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   timer1.Enabled=false;
   //Statements to start aircraft 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting it to true (or selected, or whatever you want) sleeping for 10 seconds, like this:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000) ;
```

and then set it back to false (or unselect, or whatever you want)

---

Another way to go would be to start a background thread that will sleep for ten seconds, and then call a method that will "unset" the button, this way, not blocking the GUI ...

Or depending on what you're using, I could probably come up with other options, but i'll take it you're trying to learn the basics atm ... :)

Comment: this will block operation for 10 seconds,not sure if OP wants that,else a thread listener is required

Comment: True, but he said it locks for 10 seconds ... :)

Comment: It doesn't lock *the switch*, it **blocks** the *complete UI*. Pretty sure that is not the OP's intention.

Answer (score 0):

See this one [msdn timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And you can use Threed.Sleep(10000);

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works. I didn't compile it, but with this you lock the swtich, do your stuff checking a timer that when arrives to 10 sec, re-enable your switch.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
      //Starter is off
      eng2Start.Value = 0;
   }

   if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
      //starter is on 

      starterRight.enable = false;

      StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();      

      sw.Start();
      eng2Start.Value = 1;


      if (eng2Tourqe >= 6000)
      {
         //open fuel valve
         // set Hot Start counter to 0
      }
      else 
      {
         //ensure fuel valve stays closed
         // set Hot Start counter to x+1
      }

      if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 10000)
      {
         do
         {
             //Dummy Loop
         }
         while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 10000)
         sw.Stop(); 
      }
      else
      {
          // set selected index back to 0
          sw.Stop();
          starterRight.Enabled = true;
          (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 0)
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and the [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event. Disable your switch, and when the Timer tick, Enabled it.

```
Timer timerSwitchOn;

public SomeConstructor()
{
    timerSwitchOn = new Timer(){Interval = 10*1000}; // 10 seconds
    timerSwitchOn.Tick += new EventHandler(timerSwitchOn_Tick);
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   if (starterRight.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
      //starter is on 
      starterRight.Enabled = false;
      timerSwitchOn.Start();
   }
}

void timerSwitchOn_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerSwitchOn.Stop();
    starterRight.Enabled = true;

    // set selected index back to 0
    starterRight.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my initial question I said I had wanted to invoke a loop, I meant a timer but it seems that you all figured that out.

Thank you for the rapid answers, I am going to get stuck into them this weekend and see if I can solve my problem.